# Bootstrap 4 manually invalidate input field natively

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, bootstrap-4

I want to make use of Bootstrap 4's form validation. From what I read you can invalidate a field by adding class 'is-invalid' - this works, but when I want to check the form validity using method checkValidity() it still says the form is VALID which is not what I expected. I was hoping of making use of the native bootstrap 4 functionality and not use plugins such as jquery validator etc.

```js
            $('#submit_button').on('click', function(e){
            var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');

            var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    console.log("form is INVALID")
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                } else {
                    console.log("form is VALID")
                }
                // form.classList.add('was-validated');        
                });
            })
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
    <form class="needs-validation" id="my_form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check">
            <label for="taskname_l">Task Name</label>
            <div class="form-inline">
                <input type="text" class="form-control task_form is-invalid" id="taskname_in" name="taskname_in">
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>   
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="submit_button">Submit form</button>
      </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Using JQUERY you can use the `.val()` function

To get the value of the input field with id "taskname_in" use this code

```
$('#taskname_in').val()
```

**Option 1 snippet:**

```js
$('#submit_button').on('click', function(e) {
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');

  var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
    if ($('#taskname_in').val() == '') {
      console.log("form is INVALID")
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      console.log("form is VALID")
    }
    // form.classList.add('was-validated');        
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="needs-validation" id="my_form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-check">
        <label for="taskname_l">Task Name</label>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <input type="text" class="form-control task_form" id="taskname_in" name="taskname_in">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="submit_button">Submit form</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

**Option 2:**
Using form validator to check all input-fields at once.

**Option 2 snippet:**

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom02">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" value="" required>
      <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was hoping I could just check the whole form at once instead of doing that for each field I'll have. My process will be to do numerous other checks (not just if empty) and if I don't want to pass the check I'd addClass 'is-invalid' to the input, and then right at the end check validity of the entire form.

Comment: Added option 2, checks the whole form field

Comment: Please see my reply to Pritesh K.

Answer (score 0):

'is-invalid' does not make that particular field an invalid. it just applies CSS to look as it's invalid.

Result of HTMLElement.checkValidity() depends on its Constraint.

Suppose, you add field with 'required' constrain and you run checkValidity() on the form or field while it's empty, you will receive response as false, which means that a form or field is not valid.

In your case, just add required in your input field and you will receive response as invalid if you submit form while field is empty.

Comment: ah, so that just applies the CSS - thought as much. My thing is I don't want to necessarily check for "required" as the only constraint. For example, I want to check that the input value does not yet exist in my sql-lite db via AJAX, and if it already exist, apply the IS-INVALID CSS class to the field, but then I also want it to be INVALID so when I check form validity when user click's submit - it doesn't pass. I'll have various different checks on  various inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the default Bootstrap validation code for the required fields:

```
$(".needs-validation").submit(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    form.addClass('was-validated');
  });
```

You would just need to add another validation for example on input and use the setCustomValidity. For example if you want to check for equal values on password and confirm password:

```
if ($('form input[name="confirm_password"').length > 0) {
    $('input[name="confirm_password"').on('change paste keyup', function() {
        var password = $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="password"').val();
        if($(this).val() !== password){
            this.setCustomValidity('Passwords must match');
        } else {
            this.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    });
};
```

If you have an invalid-feedback message next to the input element it will show that message instead of the one you set here.